# Probability that the person speak true (has he drawn two aces when he says so ?)

Tags: probability-theory

I tried much in this problem But I didn't get my answer correct.

The question states--

A person draws two cards successively without replacement from a pack of 52 playing cards.He tells that both cards are aces,then what is  the probability that both cards are actually aces if there are 60% chances that he speaks truth-----

My attempt -----

$P(T)=0.6$ let$ E1 $be the event that the person says that the first card drawn is ace and $E2 $be the second card drawn is ace said by the person.

Then $$P(E1)=\frac{1}{13}\cdot 0.6+\frac{48}{52}\cdot 0.4$$
Similarly  $$P(E2 \mid E1)=(\frac{7}{15}\cdot 0.6+\frac{95}{51}\cdot 0.4)\cdot (\frac{0.6}{13}+\frac{4.8}{13})$$
So,$$P(E1 \cap E2)=P(E2 \mid E1)\cdot P(E1)$$

But I am not getting the answer.please help me in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it may be 60%. He says he has two aces and there is a 60% probability he is telling the truth.

Comment: @Tom Collinge no the person after getting two cards either says he has two aces or he has no two aces.but the person says he has two aces, there must be some case in which he might not have one ace or both aces and he is lying.

Comment: Would you have to exclude the possibility that he is lying about not having two aces when he has?

Comment: Please use the exact problem statement, since this smells of an interpretation that already may be incorrect.

Comment: OK, on reflection it's more complicated than I first thought. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So probably he was lying
H1-he has 2 aces
H2-he hasn't 2 aces
p(H1)=(4  2)/(52  2)=1/(13*17)
p(H2)=1-p(H1)=1-1/(13*17)

A-he is saying he has 2 aces
p(A)=0.6*p(H1)+0.4*p(H2)

Your probability is p(H1|A)=p(H1 & A)/p(A)=$\frac{0.6 p(H1)}{p(A)}=1/147$
I'm not really sure about the final result...

Comment: thanks it really helped me solving the problem.however you have forgetten to take one more case into consideration.the fact that he has one ace and one other card and he was lying.

Comment: That case also belongs to H2

Comment: but when you have subtracted 1 from the case that he has actually picked up two aces,it also brought in unwanted cases when he has picked up more than two cards which is certain not of our concern.so we should calculate for each possible cases separately.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: see my own answer.

Comment: Ok, you have to define precisely what are the facts

1.He picked 2 cards?

2.He is saying that he picked 2 aces.(or maybe he is telling after each picking which card he picked?)

3.He has 60% chance for telling truth

Comment: @Tom Collinge  can you tell what is wrong in my statement, I'm not sure if I understood the question well?

Comment: We differ in how we calculate the probability he says he has two aces. The way you calculate your $p(A)$ is that he says so 0.6 of the time he has two aces and 0.4 of the time when he doesn't. But, when he doesn't and he lies he might say all sorts of things besides two aces. See if you agree with the logic in my answer ?

Comment: Ahm, so his statement is questionable, is it actually refers to subject or not, he may be telling about the cards he picked or about weather or something else. Was he asked if he picked 2 aces or which cards he picked?

Comment: No, the problem statement is fine, I just don't agree with your logic of how you determine your $p(A)$. Compare it to how I determine my $p(S)$.

Comment: I see difference that you allow him lots of statements, and one of it is "I picked 2 aces". I allow him just 2 statements, "I picked 2 aces" and "I didn't pick 2 aces"

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve a general problem, then check a couple of reasonable outcomes, and finally come back to the specific.

Let $E$ be an event happening with probability $p(E)  $, $S$ be a statement that the event happened made with probability $p(S)$ by a person whose statements are true with probability $p(T)$

We want to know what is the probability of the event given that the person states that it did. This is a conditional probability $p(E|S)$ and using the standard formula, $p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S)$

$p(E \& S)$ is easily determined: the probability that the event took place and the person stated it did = the probability that the event took place and the person made a true statement $= p(E).p(T)$

$p(S)$ can't be determined directly. The person can make lots of statements (in this case, he could call two kings, jack high, etc.) and we don't know the relative frequencies of them. But he either makes the statement $S$ or a different one. We can consider all the different statements together as "not S" and $p(S) = 1 - p($not $ S)$.

We can determine $p($not $ S)$ as the probability of not $E$ and he tells the truth + probability of $E$ and he lies: $p($not $ S) = (1 -p(E)).p(T) + p(E).(1 - p(T) $

So, $p(S) = 1 - (1 -p(E)).p(T) + p(E).(1 - p(T)$ and **$p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = p(E).p(T) / (1 - (1 -p(E)).p(T) + p(E).(1 - p(T))$**

We would like to see that if the person always tells the truth, then $p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = 1$, so put $p(T) = 1$ and then $p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = p(E).1 / (1 - (1 -p(E).1) + p(E).(1 - 1) = p(E)/p(E) = 1 $ (assuming a nonzero probability $p(E)$ for the event). So that works like it should.

We would also like to see that if the event can never happen (i.e. $p(E) = 0$ ) then $p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = 0$. Note that in this case the person can only make the statement $S$ if he lies, so $P(T) < 1$. Then $p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = 0.p(T) / (1 - (1 -0).p(T) + 0.(1 - p(T)) = 0/(1 -p(T)) = 0$  with $P(T) < 1$. So that works too.

We can also check what happens if the person always lies (i.e. $p(T) = 0$). then we would expect $p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = 0$.
$p(E|S) = p(E \& S)/p(S) = p(E).0 / (1 - (1 -p(E)).0 + p(E).(1 - 0) = 0/(1+p(E) = 0 $. That also works.

---

**The aces problem:**

$p(E)$ is now that probability of drawing two aces from the deck, and $p(T) = 0.6 = 3/5$. Calculate $p(E)$:

There are $^4C_2$ combinations of two aces out of 4, and $^{52}C_2$ two card draws. So, $p(E)  = ^4C_2/ ^{52}C_2$ $= (4!/2!.2!) / (52!/50!.2!) = (6)/ (52.51/2) = 6/26.51 = 1/13.17 = 1/221$

Plug this into the previous result:

$p(E|S) = (1/221).(3/5) / (1 - (1 -1/221).(3/5) + (1/221).(1 - 3/5))$ $= (3/5)/ (221 - (221 - 1).(3/5) +(1 - 3/5))$ $ = (3/5)/ (221 - 132 + 2/5) = 3/447 = 1/149.$

---

**How $p(E|S) $ varies with $p(T)$**

As a point of interest I plotted the probability that the person has two aces when he says so against the probability that he tells the truth. For an unlikely event ($p(E) = 1/221$) he has to be very truthful before you believe him: around 99.5% truthful to even have a 50% chance of him holding two aces.

[image]

Comment: "We can determine p(not S) as the probability of not E and he tells the truth + probability of E and he lies" this statement of yours isn't true, cos you didn't count when not E and he lies but not telling E, he may lying and telling something else... (of course if you allow more then 2 statements)

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov. Yes, I think I may have the same problem as you if more than two statements are allowed. More than two statements is realistic - how to solve it ?

Comment: I don't think question has much sense in that case. But if you define exact number of possible statements then ok, otherwise p(E|S)=1

Answer (score 0):

In your formula you should have the $E_1$ is the probability that $P$ is telling the truth, and $E_2$ is the probability that $P$ draws two aces. Then try again..

*And think of the possibility that $P$ lies when he has two aces.*